# prove that a 2D matrix finite difference equation is symmetric and positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, heat-equation, finite-differences

[image]hi,After doing the finite difference approximation of a 2D heat equation, I have to prove the the matrix for of this equation is symmetric end positive definite,
i don't know how to star the problem
if someone has some clues about the solution it will be amazing

Comment: What do you mean by "the matrix for this equation"?

Comment: @William Can you show that the matrix associated with the one-dimensional problem is positive definite?